# Is it possible to query a firebase firestore for 1 document that contains a unique set of keywords without it costing a fortune?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In a firebase firestore database of blog posts, i am faced with a business rule that requires me to enforce that no two blog posts can share a matching set of keywords.

Order does not matter, just that each blog post must contain a unique set of keywords.

With that said. **Is it possible to construct one query to check a collection of documents for an object of keywords that matches a given object of keywords?** no nested data btw just a list of keywords stored in an object in my firestore document.

Now, it might very well be true that i will need another data structure to achieve this, but currently i am working with the following 2 collections (update: shortened here for clarity, each post could contain anywhere from 1 - 30 keywords):

```
blogs (collection)
(blogA)
-- content
-- keywords: {car:true, truck:true, airplane:true}
(blogB)
-- content
-- keywords: {car:true, truck:true, train:true}

keywords (collection)
(car)
-- blogs: {blogA:true, blogB:true}
(truck)
-- blogs: {blogA:true, blogB:true}
(airplane)
-- blogs: {blogA:true}
(train)
-- blogs: {blogB:true}
```

using the data above as the example,

a new blog post with keywords: `car, truck, airplane` would be **denied**

a new blog post with keywords: `car, truck, airplane, bus` would be **accepted**

below is possible logic for a cloud function as an example solution, but its a bit ridiculous and  would never scale. *So for that reason I am going to leave out a lot of necessary logic that would cover all cases. I just want to get the idea across here.*

query keywords collection for each newly submitted keyword

-- if one does not exist - STOP - **allow** new blog entry
-- else create 2 empty arrays to work with

```
  blogs[]
  matches[]
```

-- for each keyword submitted, loop through its list of blog ids and push each into `blogs[]` array.

If blog id already inserted, push blog id into `matches[]` array instead.

we are left with an array `matches[]` *containing a list of all blog posts that include two or more of the newly submitted keywords*

-- `if (matches[].length === 0)` - STOP - **allow** new blog entry

-- else for each blog in `matches[]`, get its keywords object from the blog document in firestore  *but if there are millions of docs, this loop would cost a fortune*

-- if new keywords object (sorted alphabetically) === blog keywords object (sorted alphabetically) - STOP - set exists **deny** blog post

if no blogs in our matches[] array contain a matching set of keywords then we know we have a new, unique set of keywords - STOP - **allow** blog post

I have to believe there is a better approach.

Answer (score 2):

When you have a uniqueness requirement, always try to use the value(s) that must be unique as the key of the documents in your collection.

Since keys are by definition unique in a collection, using something as the key implicitly guarantees that it will be unique. It also means that the check becomes a check for the existence of a specific document, instead of a query through all documents for a value/combination of values.

In your case you could simply concatenate the categories in alphabetic/lexicographical order to generate the document key.

With that approach, these categories would lead to keys:

```
Categories                   Document id/key
---------------------------+-----------------------
car, truck, airplane       | airplane_car_truck
truck, car, airplane       | airplane_car_truck
car, truck, airplane, bus  | airplane_bus_car_truck
truck, airplane, car, bus  | airplane_bus_car_truck
```

I used `_` as the separator above, but any separator that can never occur in your categories is fine.

Comment: I understand this concept, however, in my particular case, this is not practical as a blog could contain upwards of  10 or more keywords that may also include special characters. I should add this point to the question.

Comment: @DevMike - consider using this idea with a hash of the lexically ordered, concatenated keywords.

Comment: The main point here (as lara clarified) is to use a key that is a direct representation of the values that must be unique. If you can't do that through simple concatenation, you can indeed use a hash (that is sufficiently likely to not result in clashes).

Comment: But if hashes are not guaranteed to be unique, and i will be hashing rather long strings (up to 30 keywords) aren't the chances for collision highly probable here? Is this really a viable solution for my case?

Comment: From the [Firestore quota page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas): `"Maximum size for a document name 6 KiB"`. The disallowed characters are also specified there, and it's incredibly little. So my expectation is that you won't need to even hash anything, merely encode disallowed sequences. If you *do* need to hash, a decent hash of 6KiB in size should allow for more unique combinations than you'll ever need.

Comment: I am now thinking about storing the hash inside the document and using a security rule to enforce the unique keyword set?

Comment: That brings you back to the original problem: enforcing unique will then require a query, which is not possible in security rules. I highly recommend giving the simple approach I outlined a try, and posting back with a new question if you run into concrete problems with it.